# regex not picking up new lines

Tags: regex, delphi

https://regex101.com/r/zAt2dw/3

I am seaching for lines like so

```
{"url":"/search?cflt=active&amp;find_loc=37801","name":"Active Life"},
```

but as u can see in 101 example

```
{"url":"\/search\?cflt=[^<>]+?&amp;find_loc=37801","name":"[^<>]+?"},
```

match1 is huge and match 8 has 2 lines instead of 1

Comment: Your regex is greedy. Make it non-greedy by changing `[^<>]+` to `[^<>]+?` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAt2dw/2)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi i updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use lazy quantifiers: `+?` instead of `+`.

Comment: i updated question please help

Comment: Your regex matches more because of `[^<>]` parts. Try to exclude other symbols, which are not parts of the fields you are trying to match. For example, `[^\"<>]`. However by doing that you wouldn't find fields which have `"` in them, there may be some better strategy.